# Camel Aggregation wait for lock

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel 2.25.0 route listening to a JMS queue which aggregates on a key. The aggregation is configured with a 10 minutes completion timeout, a `LevelDBAggregationRepository` and the `UseLatestAggregationStrategy`.

```
from("jms:inbound")
        .log("Received views change stream")
        .bean(viewService, "updateDependencies")
        .aggregate()
        .header("JMSXGroupID")
        .aggregationStrategy(new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
        .completionTimeout(600000) // 10 minutes
        .completeAllOnStop()
        .aggregationRepository(new LevelDBAggregationRepository("aggregation-repository", "./aggregation-repository"))
        .log("Process views change stream")
        .to("jms:outbound");
```

From time to time, the thread is blocked and the queue is not consumed. When it happens the logs show that there is a wait between the `updateDependencies` call and the start of the aggregation. `XXXX` is the end of the previous aggregation, and `YYYY` is the blocked aggregation.

```
APM duration: 1,073.2s
August 7th 2020, 11:39:20.327   onAggregation +++  end  +++ with correlation key: XXXX
August 7th 2020, 11:39:20.327   Received views change stream
August 7th 2020, 11:39:20.341   1 documents touched based on update // log from updateDependencies
August 7th 2020, 11:57:13.555   onAggregation +++ start +++ with correlation key: YYYY
```

In `AggregateProcessor`, there is a lock before the aggregation

```
lock.lock();
try {
    aggregated = doAggregation(key, copy);
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

My guess is that the wait time is due to the lock but it does not make sense since we can see that the previous aggregation (`XXXX`) is finished, so the lock should be released.

I also checked the application, and other threads are still running.